# Annoying Pop Up Using Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2

I keep getting this annoying pop up of the user path while using Sublime.  It seems to pop up when I have errors.  It's really annoying and I don't know how to stop it.  I tried looking in the settings and uninstalling ESLint (since that was the last package I installed)  Still popping up.

[image]

Comment: Those are phantoms. If it's Sublime doing it, setting `show_errors_inline` to `false` in your user settings will turn it off. If that has no effect then you have a plugin/package that's doing it that should have a comparable configuration option.

Comment: It seems to have worked.  I originally tried to change the settings in the default and not in the user.  Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.